# Operator with two Boolean in python

Tags: python, boolean, operators

Why does not work the Operator "&" in this two expressions?

```
# First, type bool
bool(re.search(r'\d', "4foo"))
>True
# Second, type bool
len("4foo")==4
>True
type(len("4foo")==4)))
>bool
```

When using both with Operator "&" like this I get `False` which is not supossed to be correct:

```
# Expected output as this example:
True&True
>True

# The "wrong" output:
 bool(re.search(r'\d', "4foo"))& (len("4foo")==4)
>False
```

After an hour getting crazy I "solved" this by using that I never expected to be the "problem":

```
# The "correct" output(transforming a bool type into a bool type something that works but seems stupid...):
 bool(re.search(r'\d', "4foo"))&bool(len("4foo")==4)
>True
```

## Solution

```
bool(re.search(r'\d', "4foo")) and len("4foo")==4
```

Comment: This is wrong `len("4foo"==4)`, I guess it should be `len("4foo") == 4`. Anyways use `and` instead of &

Comment: In python when you compering booleans you need use 'and' or 'or' words to compare.

Comment: What's this `len("4foo")==4))`?

Comment: Because `&` is the **bitwise and** operator, not the boolean and operator, which in Python is `and`. and it's precedence is different

Comment: Also note that the `&` operator is bitwise and, use the `and` operator for Boolean logic

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the typo errors are corrected...

Comment: When pasting this `bool(re.search(r'\d', "4foo"))& (len("4foo")==4)` in my python shell, I have the expected (well, kind of...) `True` result. But you should be using the logical `and`  operator here nonetheless (and get rid of those useless `bool()` calls - Python objects all have a truth value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

Replace `&` with `and`:

```
In [638]: bool(re.search(r'\d', "4foo")) and len("4foo")==4                                                                                                                                                 
Out[638]: True
```

`and` tests whether both expressions are logically True while `&` (when used with True/False values) tests if both are True.

Comment: Since `and` tests if both it's operand are true (which is the mere definition of a logical 'and' in boolean arithmetic), your explanation about the bitwise `&` operator doesn't help.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `bool(something)` when using logical `and` - Python objects all have a truth value when used in a boolean context.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention about parentheses

```
len("4foo"==4) ------------> len("4foo")==4
```

and condition

```
re.search(r'\d', "4foo")and len("4foo")==4
```